# Toggle readonly filesystem for changes

Tags: linux, sudo, readonly, disk, mbr

I have a readonly filesystem on my bootable usb drive.

I want to modify some text files in there and then bring it back to readonly after modify it.

I tried :

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

I also tried :

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb
```

mount: /dev/sdb: mount point not mounted or bad option.

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1
```

cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected.

But it's stays readonly.

I do not want to make any other changes to the partition it's important to keep all the rest of the partition/mbr as is.

Any idea?

Comment: mount -o remount,rw /foo

Comment: @stark I tried this as well. Not working ... :(

Comment: @stark mount: /dev/sdb: mount point not mounted or bad option.

mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb

Comment: most likely the device is wrong. Are you sure it's not /dev/sdb1

Comment: @stark cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected.

Comment: What filesystem? iso is read-only

Comment: @stark I was using sudo dd if=boot.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress ### Probably it write it as write protected but I want to modify it ###

Comment: depends also on the file system... iso, squashfs are read only...

Comment: @OznOg It's was an iso now all files are extracted but still can not modify

Comment: what do you mean by extracted? btw, you will need to recreate an iso after, thus you should have a look to mkisofs